installing and running unit tests in qt creator with qt testing framework and qmake compiler
I'm currently grappling with a project for my university, and my team and I are navigating through the intricacies of Qt Creator. As we configured our project, we opted to employ qmake, and while some of us delved into coding, a colleague and I embarked on the endeavor of installing the Google Test framework. However, despite our best efforts, the project failed to detect the framework files, leading us to abandon the pursuit.
Now, we find ourselves endeavoring to implement unit tests utilizing the Qt Testing framework, but we're encountering obstacles in the process. Allow me to present our current predicament:
Within our .pro file, we are attempting the following:
    QT       += core gui sql testlib

    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-private-field

    CONFIG += c++17

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        CONFIG += console
    }

    test {
        message(test build) 
        QT += testlib
        TARGET = demo-test
        INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/test
        SOURCES += \
            arztview.cpp \
            behandlungsraum.cpp \
            datenbearbeitenview.cpp \
            letztetermineview.cpp \
            main.cpp \
            login.cpp \
            patientenview.cpp \
            registrierenview.cpp \
            terminabsagenview.cpp \
            terminhinzufugenview.cpp \
            user.cpp

        HEADERS += \
            arztview.h \
            behandlungsraum.h \
            datenbearbeitenview.h \
            letztetermineview.h \
            login.h \
            patientenview.h \
            registrierenview.h \
            terminabsagenview.h \
            terminhinzufugenview.h \
            user.h
    }
    else {
        message(normal build) 
        SOURCES += \
            arztview.cpp \
            behandlungsraum.cpp \
            datenbearbeitenview.cpp \
            letztetermineview.cpp \
            main.cpp \
            login.cpp \
            patientenview.cpp \
            registrierenview.cpp \
            terminabsagenview.cpp \
            terminhinzufugenview.cpp \
            user.cpp

        HEADERS += \
            arztview.h \
            behandlungsraum.h \
            datenbearbeitenview.h \
            letztetermineview.h \
            login.h \
            patientenview.h \
            registrierenview.h \
            terminabsagenview.h \
            terminhinzufugenview.h \
            user.h

        FORMS += \
            arztview.ui \
            datenbearbeitenview.ui \
            letztetermineview.ui \
            login.ui \
            patientenview.ui \
            registrierenview.ui \
            terminabsagenview.ui \
            terminhinzufugenview.ui
    }

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

Additionally, we've configured two build options, "test" and "debug," for both regular and test builds.
Our primary quandary arises when attempting to execute the "test" build. The compiler erroneously processes the .ui files, which should be confined to the "else" branch, not the "test." Simultaneously, we receive the message "test build" in the console.
We attempted to compile the "test" build but encountered an immediate issue. Instead of compiling only the test files, the compiler processed and displayed the .ui files, which, in our understanding, shouldn't happen. Initially, we suspected that the condition in the "else" branch might not have been used correctly. However, since the console displays the message "test build," we are now uncertain about how to proceed further.
We attempted to compile the "test" build but encountered an immediate issue. Instead of compiling only the test files, the compiler processed and displayed the .ui files, which, in our understanding, shouldn't happen. Initially, we suspected that the condition in the "else" branch might not have been used correctly. However, since the console displays the message "test build," we are now uncertain about how to proceed further.
